# (Tkinter) How to get entry button to appear after button is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the user to enter a value after clicking a button. I tried to define the entry within the function for clicking the button but nothing appears? The labels change when the button is clicked as per what I configured them to in the function but the entry does not appear.

```
def jan():
    Birth_Month = "January"
    January.forget()
    February.forget()
    March.forget()
    April.forget()
    May.forget()
    June.forget()
    July.forget()
    August.forget()
    September.forget()
    October.forget()
    November.forget()
    December.forget()
    Title.configure(text="So you were born in January")
    Month.configure(text="What date in January?")
    Date = tkinter.Entry(window)
    Birth_Date = Date.get()
    Birth_Date = Birth_Date.int()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your widget to show up, you need to use one of the geometry managers (`pack`, `grid`, `place`) on your object.

```
Date = tkinter.Entry(window)
Date.pack() # or grid, place depending on rest of your code
```

Also, to not create *new* `Entry` every time, you should create `Entry` outside of your function in global scope and `pack` it inside of your function.

```
Date = tkinter.Entry(window) # somewhere in your code that is accessible to your method

def jan():
    Date.pack()
```

Comment: @Nia if this answer worked for you please select the check mark next to the answer to show your issue has been resolved.